# Rewrite all html pages

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need clean urls (e.g. example.com/test) to redirect all requests without a file extension to html pages (so I can still call programmed pages without rewriting). I made a file that I hoped should do this, but it doesn't :/ Any ideas?

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. You have to set a RewriteCond(ition). Otherwise there's a infinite Loop...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this line on top:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```